# How to add linebreak in text from json to react

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering some cards which has some texts. The texts and card images are kept in a json file, and I am looping through the card elements. One of the text on the card needs a linebreak, and I am not quite sure how to do that. The cards are rending here

```
{data.section2.cards.map((item, index) => {
  const img = imgUrl.base + item.img;
  return (
    <CustomColumn padding={'0'} md={6} lg="3" key={`sc2${index}`}>
      <CardComponent
        img={img}
        msize={'320px'}
        text={intl.formatMessage(messages[item.text])}
      />
    </CustomColumn>
  );
})}
```

The item.text refers to a key:

```
{
  "type": "footerText",
  "img": "home/section-3/boxes/3/image%402x.png",
  "text": "section4_image3_text"
},
```

and the "section4_image3_text" refers to a json file which has the original text  `"app.components.HomePage.section4_image3_text": "Large Fleet"` . 
I have googled and from the react documentation I found that I need to implement this:

```
text.split('\n').map((item, i) => {
  return <p key={i}>{item}</p>;
});
```

But I am very new to react and not sure how to do this. Any help on this ?

Comment: Your JSON string needs to have a newline character `\n` in it for that snippet to work.

Comment: I understand that. But how can I integrate that code to mine?

Comment: Do you just want to add a line break after the text? Then why don't you just do `messages[item.text]) + '\n'`? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I want to add a line break in between the text. I have 6 texts, and the line break is required within only one of them. i.e "Large \n Fleet" instead of "Large Fleet"

Comment: ``padding={'0'} md={6} lg="3"`` you should keep one style here :D